# Почему по разному выводятся даты

Tags: javascript, php, sqlite

**ajax.php**

```
function showTable($tbl,$viewmode){
    # функция собирает разметку таблицы из базы
}
```

**#1**
На странице кнопка которая запрашивает инфу:

**JS**

```
fetch("http://dbserver.ru/ajax.php?showTable="+name+"&ajax=true")
    .then(r=>r.text())
    .then(r=>{
        get("#maincontent").innerHTML=r
        history.pushState({ "showTable": name }, name, "http://dbserver.ru?showTable=" + name)
    })
```

**#2**
если обновить страницу то данные выводятся в index.php:

```
require_once("ajax.php");

if(isset($_GET["showTable"]))
    echo showTable($_GET["showTable"],$viewmode);
```

Даты в базе записаны как 01.01.2020.
В первом случае даты выводятся нормально, во втором, если обновить страницу по F5 они превращаются в "2020-01-01".
Даты нигде не форматируются.
Почему так происходит?

**UPD**  столбец в базе DateTime

Comment: если столбец в базе DateTime, то даты в базе **не могут быть** записаны как 01.01.2020.

Comment: разные языки и программы отображают даты по своему, это нужно учитывать ничего в этом необычного нет